# What is the correct way to pass static HTML files to template?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

For example, let's say I have a HandleBars template called main.handlebars like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div> {{ html1 }} </div>
<div> {{ html2 }} </div>
<div> {{ html3 }} </div>
</body>
```

And then I have html1.html:

```
<p1>Blah</p1>
```

html2.html:

```
<p1>Blah</p1>
```

html3.html:

```
<p1>Blah</p1>
```

What's the correct way to load html1.html, html2.html, and html3.html and pass them to the main.handlebars template?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide more information on what you are trying to achieve.

However, generally when using a client-side templating library like Handlebars or Mustache you will first compile your template, then pass your data object to the compiled template function.

### Using your example above:

```
<body>
<div> {{ html1 }} </div>
<div> {{ html2 }} </div>
<div> {{ html3 }} </div>
</body>
```

You would first compile the template:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('body').innerHTML);
```

Then output the result using a data object, or model:

```
var output = document.querySelector('.output');
output.innerHTML = template(data);
```

I've created a simple working example here: http://codepen.io/chrsr/pen/ZQvgEx

---

If, what you're trying to do, is take the "html" files with the content: `<p1>blah</p1>` you will need to transform these files in to a readable format by the template library.

> Note: `<p1>` is not a valid HTML element, where are these coming from?

To do this, you could use something like this: http://codepen.io/chrsr/pen/PZEMZz?editors=1010 - a simple example of manipulating your `<p1>blah</p1>` data in to a JS object).

---

I've explained the basic concepts of a templating library like Handlebars, but if you're after a different answer I would suggest setting up a CodePen demo or providing more information in your question.

Comment: Given that the question was tagged with `node.js` and `express`, I think it's fair to assume that it's related to server-side rendering, not client-side.